# Xamarin Forms/Prism Custom Popup

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

How can I create a custom dialog/popup in Xamarin Forms, that works with Prism's navigation?

Prism supports an IPageDialogService which is great, but doesn't allow customization of the content of that dialog.

I'd like to have a simple ok/cancel popup that allows various UI controls (ie, entry fields, radio buttons, etc). I tried incorporating the Rg.Plugins.Popup but it requires you use a their PopupNavigation service, and I'd rather avoid using different navigation patterns.

Comment: You have to create CustomRenders for that. Or try Acr.UserDialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Prism.Plugin.PageDialogs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Plugin.PageDialogs) provides a custom PageDialogService for Prism.Forms using the Popup plugin.
[Prism.Plugin.Popups.Unity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Plugin.Popups.Unity/) provides a extensions to INavigationService to allow Prism friendly navigation for Popup Pages. There is a package for each of the Prism.Forms supported containers.

Both are currently pre-release, but hopefully they help solve your problem.

Comment: Dan, thanks so much for your quick response.  I used the PopupExtensions to show the popup (based on Rg.Plugins.Popup) and this works well.  But I'm confused about how I would make use of the PageDialogs. Could you explain a bit more?  What would the advantage be to using that alternative?

Comment: There's an example in the [ReadMe](https://github.com/dansiegel/Prism.Plugin.PageDialogs). You can implement the look and feel you want using a either an ```ActionSheetBase : PopupPage``` or ```AlertPageBase : PopupPage```. You simply need to override the functions for returning your implementation of the page, or you can use the one's provided by the plugin. If you need something more feel free to open an issue.

Comment: @DanS. great but what if my popup doesn't have title or message? Because I see I must use either `GetActionSheet` and `GetAlertPage`, I don't have a "generic" method to show a custom popup. Something like `GetMyPopup()`

Comment: @DonBox can't say I've ever tried not passing in a title for the built in Alert. That said you can do anything you need with the Popup Plugin, and you can use custom pages for the PageDialogs Plugin