# Custom ActionSheet Xamarin Forms + Prism

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am doing cart program. What I wanted to do is when a user clicks on a item it needs to display a custom action sheet where user can enter the quantity for that item.

At present I am doing with 2 pages. Once user clicks it will navigate to another where user can enter the quantity.

I can do it with Xamarin Android. However I don't have an idea how can I achieve it with Xamarin Forms and Prism.

Any guidance will be most welcome.

also this doesn't  work for me.
[Xamarin Forms/Prism Custom Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646434/xamarin-forms-prism-custom-popup)

Comment: Can you provide more information as to what doesn't work for you? If you are using an ActionSheet, then you would use `IPageDialogService`, if you need a totally customized look you should use a PopupPage using [Prism.Plugin.Popups](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Plugin.Popups.Unity/)

Comment: No I meant is it possible to customize actionsheet. so that can be used with  IPageDialogService

Answer (score 0):

Neither the ActionSheet or the ActionSheet are directly customizable since the Prism service just abstracts the call to the underlying Xamarin Forms DisplayAlert or ActionSheet methods. There is preview of a Plugin for providing custom ActionSheets and AlertDialogs using a customized PopupPage. You can checkout the [Prism.Plugin.PageDialogs](https://github.com/dansiegel/Prism.Plugin.PageDialogs) on GitHub.